# Disable WordPress routes except for the JSON API and admin UI

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-rest-api

I'm planning to use my WordPress installation as a headless and only consume data via WP API (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) in the front-end.

But by default, the UI of the client-facing website is visible to all the users and I want to make sure that if a customer opens a website it gets redirected to my front end.

To make it clear, here's examples:

- open: wordpress-example.com -> redirect to my-api-example.com
- open: wordpress-example.com/any-route -> redirect to my-api-example.com
  etc.
- open: wordpress-example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts -> return API
  response
- open: wordpress-example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories ->
  return API response etc.
- open: wordpress-example.com/wp-admin.php -> opens WP Admin

Solution 1:
Maybe there is a global setting in WordPress or a separate plug-in that disables the UI.
I could not find it.

Solution 2: Adjust the .thaccess file to exclude `/wp-admin.php` and `/wp-json/` routes
https://fedingo.com/how-to-exclude-folder-from-rewrite-rule-in-htaccess/

Comment: Have you thought about just using a proxy?

Comment: @BretWeinraub could you propose a solution that I can add on my WP site, without extra app that does the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place a redirect at the beginning of your `header.php` file

```
$parts = parse_url( home_url() );
$current_uri = "{$parts['scheme']}://{$parts['host']}" . add_query_arg( NULL, NULL );
$url_parsed = wp_parse_url($current_uri);
$new_url = 'https://my-api-example.com' . $url_parsed['path'];
wp_safe_redirect($new_url);
exit;
```

Comment: in my case just adding `header('Location: '.$newURL);` worked, but thanks for suggestion to use header.php

Comment: The function adds the url parameters to the new url as well. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 2: Adjust the .thaccess file to exclude /wp-admin.php and /wp-json/ routes

At the top of the root `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordpress-example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^(wp-admin\.php$|wp-json/) https://my-api-example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

This assumes both `wordpress-example.com` and `my-api-example.com` resolve to the same place. If not then you can remove the preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks the requested `Host` header.

The *negated* regex `!^(wp-admin\.php$|wp-json/)` matches all URL-paths except `/wp-admin.php` (exactly) and anything that *starts* `/wp-json/`. Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not itself start with a slash.

Note that this redirects all requests (bar the stated exceptions) to the document root at `my-api-example.com`, as per your example. If you want to preserve the requested URL-path then change the *substitution* string (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) like so:

```
RewriteRule !^(wp-admin\.php$|wp-json/) https://my-api-example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 301, but only once you have confirmed that this works as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

HOWEVER, I suspect you will need to make more exceptions for the "admin" page to be accessible. What about all the static assets (images, CSS, JS, etc.)? I would refrain from excluding any request that simply maps to a physical file since this won't necessarily redirect requests that perhaps should be redirected.

To make additional exceptions for known directory locations then include additional *conditions* on the rule. For example, to make an exception for the `/wp-admin/` directory (and all files/directories within) then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
:
```

You can of course modify the existing `RewriteRule` *pattern*, although that can get messy if you have many additional exceptions to add.